# variable gets lost when using window.onload

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics, window.onunload

I have the following script, however the variable "ClientID" somehow gets lost (undefined). I'm wondering if this is because of the "window.load" statement? and is there anything I can do to make sure the ClientID variable is carried over to this function?

```
<script>
            //Google analytics include
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

            //store clientId in ClientID variable
            var ClientID = ga(function(tracker) {
                return tracker.get('clientId');
            });

            //After whole DOM is loaded addEventListener and send ClientID
            //Not working, somehow ClientID gets lost...
             window.onload = function () { 
                var myl = document.querySelector('div.mylivechat_collapsed');
                myl.addEventListener('click', function() {
                   ga('send', 'event', 'contact', 'livechat' , ClientID);
                });
            }
</script>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#adding-commands-to-the-queue

Comment: Hi Teemu, not sure how help file helps - can't find anything for this case. I'm having a problem with the order things are getting initialised, I think, and the variable gets lost.

Comment: "Invoking the ga() command queue function with the following function signature will push commands onto the queue ..." You're trying to get a value from an asynchronously executed function.

Comment: Have you checked the assigned value of `ClientID`? I'm guessing it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Yes, I see what you're saying. Is there now way to get this value and pass it in as an event?

Answer (score 0):

Per this document: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#create

The `ga()` function returns `undefined`. Therefore, `ClientID` is going to be `undefined`.

I'm not sure what you're wanting exactly, but perhaps you mean to say:

```
        window.onload = function () { 
           console.log('onload');
            var myl = document.querySelector('div.mylivechat_collapsed');
            myl.addEventListener('click', function() {
               console.log('CLICK:',ClientID);
               ga('send', 'event', 'contact', 'livechat' , tracker.get('clientId'));
            });
        }
```

If that's the case, you don't need the variable `ClientID`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ClientId is not *lost* but *never defined*:

```html
<script>
  //Google analytics include
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

            //store clientId in ClientID variable
            var ClientID = ga(function(tracker) {
                return tracker.get('clientId');
            });
    
            console.log('1:',ClientID);

            //After whole DOM is loaded addEventListener and send ClientID
            //Not working, somehow ClientID gets lost...
             window.onload = function () { 
               console.log('onload');
                var myl = document.querySelector('div.mylivechat_collapsed');
                myl.addEventListener('click', function() {
                   console.log('CLICK:',ClientID);
                   ga('send', 'event', 'contact', 'livechat' , ClientID);
                });
            }
</script>
<div class="mylivechat_collapsed">[CLICK ME]</div>
```